# How to allow apps in Django to know that the login-process has been done?

Tags: python, django, authentication

In my Django project, there are several apps( app1,app2,app3).
App1 has several view model inside views including the login and authenticate.
After I logged in, the webpage moves back to the 'home' and my base.html has following command to show the username.
 This base.html file is shared along the entire apps in the project.

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="/">{{ request.user.username }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="/accounts/logout">Logout</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li><a href="/accounts/login">Login</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
```

Funny thing is that the other app2 and app3 don't show the username and still showing only "Login" on the navbar-nav. I guess it has to be showing `"user_name + Logout"`.
 I had thought the login process hadn't occurred, but it seems that this process worked well looking the system in a sense that I masked app2 and app3 unless they are logged correctly in using @login_required.
 So when I don't login in the app1, app2 and 3 don't work. But it is not responding to `{{request.user.username}}`.

App2 and 3 have their own views.py. I can't mix entire views all together not to make the code super dirty. How can I fix this issue to show correct username and "Logout" sign after logged in?

Below are the codes for app2(poll) and app1(signups)

**[poll.vies.py]**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.http import Http404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from polls.models import Poll
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import render
from polls.models import Choice, Poll
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required



@login_required
def index(request):
    #with this way, I no longer need to import loader, Request context, httpresponse.
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

**[signups.views.py]**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib import auth

#from django.core.paginator import Paginator, InvalidPage, EmptyPage
#from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


from .forms import SignUpForm



def home(request):
    #The below line is very critical!! :)
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        save_it = form.save(commit=False)
        save_it.save()
        #send_mail(subject,message,from_email,to_list,fail_silently=True)
        subject = 'Thank you'
        message = 'Welcome home /n I am so happy'
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_list = [save_it.email,settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER ]
        #send_mail(subject,message,from_email,['christdavid@naver.com'], fail_silently=True)
        send_mail('Subject here', 'Wow, this email sending altorithm is working.\n What a marvelous function is.', settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
    to_list, fail_silently=False)


        messages.success(request, 'goodgood')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thank-you/')
    return render_to_response("signup.html", locals(),
                              context_instance = RequestContext(request))



def login(request):
    return render_to_response('login.html', locals(), RequestContext(request))

def authenticate(request):
    user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
    if user == None:
        return HttpResponse('username or password error')

    auth.login(request, user)
        #I requested "request"!!!!


    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next', '/') or '/')

def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def signup(request):
    return render_to_response('signup.html', locals(), RequestContext(request))

def create(request):
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'], 
                                    email=request.POST['email'],
                                    password=request.POST['password'])
    print 'create', user
    user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
    print 'authenticated', user
    auth.login(request, user)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next', '/') or '/')
```

Comment: in each view of the application print request.user and check you are getting logged in user name or not. And instead of {{ request.user.username }} put {{ user.username }}

Comment: {{ request.user }} should and will get the user data in template

Comment: User.username works for app2. But I don't know it's not working for app3. I am still figuring out why this is happening.

Comment: {{request.user}} doesn't give any feedback to me. Is this supposed to produce all variables under the user for example username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in each view of the application print request.user and check you are getting logged in user name or not.

And instead of {{ request.user.username }} put {{ user.username }}

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li><a href="/">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
            <li><a href="/accounts/logout">Logout</a></li>
            {% else %}
            <li><a href="/accounts/login">Login</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
```

Now check its working or not

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, but is there any chance that some app can work with your remedy and other app might not work with well? My other app is still showing "Login" instead of "Logout" and doesn't give me {{user.username}}

Comment: I did everything I could do and it turned out that, the other app is using render_to_response instead of render. When render_to_response is used, username is not printed out. Now I changed all to simple "render" and worked. But why wasn't working before? Would you let me know any reason for this?

Comment: May be there is some mistake in context variables what you are sending to templates. Check the syntax of render_to_response again.